# Is there a way to control flow of C++ code from outside?

Tags: c++11

I have a sample code :

```
#include<iostream>
main()
{
    int i = 10; //Line 1
    std::cout<<" i : "<<i; //Line 2
}
```

I want to somehow insert another statement (lets say one more std::cout) between Line-1 and Line 2.

Direct way is to change the source code and add required line. But for my source code compilation takes lot of time, so i can't afford to change the code frequently. So i want an automatic way such that i will be able to execute any statement in any function from outside so that upon hitting that function it execute my newly given statement.

I am not sure if this is possible or not. But any direction in writing the original code in such a way that my requirement can be fulfilled would be helpful.

[for debugging prupose]

Answer (score 0):

If you want new C++ code to be executed, it must first be compiled. I don't think you can avoid that. You can however try to reduce how long the compilation takes, through various practices such as using header guards and being selective with headers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot you can do in gdb to modify the behaviour of your program when it hits a nonstop breakpoint. The print command can also be used to change values, eg `print i=0` actually sets i to zero.

Just remember that all these changes and hacks need to be ported back into the source code and tested again! I have lost many excellent edits over the years doing inline hacks in running code, and then exiting without reviewing the changes.